# Rails 4: model relationships and indexing for two has_many through models

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, indexing, arel

My scenario is as follows

Company has_many purchases as a polymorphic relationship

User has_many purchases as a polymorphic relationship

Note: There is no relationship between users and companies

Purchase belongs_to polymorphism

Purchase has_many items

User has_many items through purchases

Code wise

```
class User
  has_many :purchases, as: :purchasable, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :items, through: :purchases
end

class Purchase
  belongs_to :purchasable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
end

class Item
  belongs_to :purchase
end
```

Question 1:
  What is the appropriate indexing for `User.first.items` ?

Question 2:
  I want to find the most recently purchased items grouping them by the item category. What is the most efficient indexing/arel/sql for this? Current, and I'm sure inefficient, code for this is as follows

```
class User  
  def most_recent_items
    item_ids = Item.select("MAX(id) AS id").group(:category, :puchase_id).collect(&:id) & items.collect(&:id)
    Item.order("created_at DESC").where(:id => item_ids)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As for your first question, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'appropriate indexing' - but if you mean that calling `user.items` isn't working for you, I think the simplest solution would be to create a class method in User.rb.

```
def items
  purchases.map(&:items).flatten
end
```

As for the second, there are a couple of ways you can order your items. If your results are an ActiveRecord Collection then you can use `order` much like you are in your example. If the results are an array, I'd recommend using the `sort_by` method.

```
def most_recent_items
  self.items.sort_by(&:created_at)
end
```

Note that if sorting that way doesn't put your items in the order you want you can just add a `.reverse` to the end. Hope this helps!

Comment: The issue that I'm having is that the db table is very large, 2+ mil records, and both queries are very slow. So user.items works, however, it's very slow and I wanted to see what indicies should be added to the db in order to speed it up.

Comment: Ah, if speed is your concern I would recommend using elasticsearch / searchkick gem. It will index all the fields of a model and parse that data much faster than an ActiveRecord query. Shy of that you'd have to slim down the data that you store on your items, maybe make use of more associations and store less on the Item object.